# Customize doxygen output for PDF LATEX

Tags: latex, doxygen, pdflatex

**Problem**:
Cannot customize the Doxygen output for LATEX to hide the page content. DoxgentLayout.xml gives you the ability to show or hide pages for HTML. looking for something equivalent

**Why**:
I need to remove/hide the pages type. The reason is because I use the modules type to create a tree hierarchy of the detailed design document which is a md file with the classes associated with the design. I use grouping to group the md file and classes together. The reason I have to hide the pages type in doxygen is because as soon as you put \ingroup at the top the .md file the content after that line will not show up this results in a series of blank pages so I just hide them because the content is within the module. So DoxgenLayout.xml will allow me to hide the pages for HTML but I don't have an equivalent for LATEX.

**What I have tried**:

- I tried modifying the refman.tex file after it was generated. When I run make for the LATEX output it always fails. So I don't know if LATEX realizes that the file changed and fails its build or I am doing something wrong.
- I tried using the LATEX_HEADER file but same result. I think this was intended to change the style of your PDF more so then what content is shown

at the top of my md files I do this:

```
\defgroup g_SystemService SystemService Library
\defgroup g_ICP-SCP ICP-SCP
\ingroup g_SystemService g_ICP-SCP 


# ICP-SCP System
This system provides...
```

The PDF output results in this:

[image: outuput pdf blank page]

**HTML output I can hide this by just modifying the DoxygenLayout.xml file to say**:

```
 <navindex>

    <tab type="pages" visible="no" title="" intro=""/>
```

**refman.tex generation (what I want to is remove these chapters from generation)**:

```
...
%--- Begin generated contents ---
% want to remove these pages
\chapter{Base\+Data\+Model}
\label{md_architecture_Common_datamodels_BaseDataModel}
\Hypertarget{md_architecture_Common_datamodels_BaseDataModel}
\input{md_architecture_Common_datamodels_BaseDataModel}
\chapter{Commands}
\label{md_architecture_SystemService_ICP_Commands}
\Hypertarget{md_architecture_SystemService_ICP_Commands}
\input{md_architecture_SystemService_ICP_Commands}
\chapter{I\+C\+P-\/\+S\+CP}
\label{md_architecture_SystemService_ICP_ICP-SCP}
\Hypertarget{md_architecture_SystemService_ICP_ICP-SCP}
\input{md_architecture_SystemService_ICP_ICP-SCP}
\chapter{I\+C\+P-\/\+S\+C\+P\+Manager}
\label{md_architecture_SystemService_ICP_ICP-SCPManager}
\Hypertarget{md_architecture_SystemService_ICP_ICP-SCPManager}
\input{md_architecture_SystemService_ICP_ICP-SCPManager}
\chapter{I\+C\+P\+Comm}
\label{md_architecture_SystemService_ICP_ICPComm}
\Hypertarget{md_architecture_SystemService_ICP_ICPComm}
\input{md_architecture_SystemService_ICP_ICPComm}
\chapter{Unit\+Tests}
\label{md_architecture_SystemService_ICP_UnitTests}
\Hypertarget{md_architecture_SystemService_ICP_UnitTests}
\input{md_architecture_SystemService_ICP_UnitTests}
% end of removing pages
\chapter{Todo List}
\label{todo}
...
```

**Doxygen Version**: 1.8.17

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? What do you mean by "I need to remove/hide the pages type"?  Did you have a look at he `doxygen.sty`  / and the doxyen settingpossibility of `LATEX_EXTRA_STYLESHEET`> All in all a small example showing what you want to accomplis / what is wrong (image) might be very useful.

Comment: @albert I updated my issue with more details. I am trying to remove pages that result in blank because when I use the \ingroup command in my md files the pages wont show any content after that point. Which is fine I just want to remove the generation of that page because its content is actually covered in the modules section. No I have not tried ```doxgen.sty```. No i didnt know about ```LATEX_EXTRA_STYLESHEET``` I will look into this maybe it can help. If you have any recommendations or advice on what I can do to modify the pdf please let me know. thanks!

Comment: Seen the comment my first quick comment regarding `doxygen.sty` and `LATEX_EXTRA_STYLESHEET` this is something that they won't help here.

Comment: Empty pages are always a nuisance. I see that these empty pages are also present in other formats like RTF, DocBook. The intention of the DoxygenLayoout file is primary for the HTML output but is not optimal (even with HTML Help, chm, I see still some remainders). The only thing, at the moment I do see, is to edit out the lines from the refaman.tex, but I'm not sure whether this will be OK in all cases and won't lead to hyperlinks that are not reachable anymore (the warning in the doxygen documentation also states this).

Comment: Yeah that is where I am at as well. I can't even modify the refman.tex. calling Make after running the refman.tex results in an error. This makes me believe there is some check that occurs  to ensure the redman.tex is the generated one. I know this because if just put a comment in the refman.tex and save it i get an error. unless there is some special tool I need to be saving it I am just using a text editor to modify.

Comment: When using a normal text / code editor that does not add special characters one can update the refman.tex (I have done / do that often especially when debugging problems). Which editor do you use? There is no check to be sure that the generated refman.tex is the one used. What s the error you get (even when adding a simple comment)?

Comment: Yeah you were correct. The default text editor for ubuntu didn't know how  to add the special characters. When using vs code to edit the file ingot better results. I created a python script to just remove the chapters that were blank and that seemed to work. This will probably due the trick for now but I still have one formatting problem which is creating the module tree view structure (groups with sub groups). Everything I have found on line regarding this seems to lead to a dead end. But I will take progress of removing the blank pages

Comment: You mention " but I still have one formatting problem which is creating the module tree view structure (groups with sub groups)", what do you mean by this how does it appear ? (probably best to create a new question for this when it is not related to the same problem).

Comment: ok will do. I think I can close this question for now because I don't think there is a solution for this. Its an enhancement to doxygen that is needed